# How to arrange data according to their creation time in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have to order data according to their creation time but

[image: Its rendering like this]

views.py

```
def email_template_list(request):
# users = User.objects.all()
if (request.user.role == 'ADMIN' or request.user.is_superuser):
    queryset = EmailTemplate.objects.all()
else:
    queryset = EmailTemplate.objects.filter(
        created_by=request.user)
users = User.objects.filter(
    id__in=queryset.values_list('created_by_id', flat=True))
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST.get('template_name'):
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            title__icontains=request.POST.get('template_name'))

    if request.POST.get('created_by'):
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            created_by=request.POST.get('created_by'))

data = {'email_templates': queryset, 'users': users}
return render(request, 'marketing/email_template/index.html', data)
```

Can i do it in Django template also??

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to order in template? You can do it in view context:

```
data = {'email_templates': queryset.order_by('-created_by'), 'users': users}
```

Comment: What order you have as result and what is your expected order? @ManasRanjanPati